# Using operations like std::remove_pointer to build derivative types in templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits, typename

So when I have code like:

```
shared_ptr<Foo> bar (my_normal_operator<Foo>(mumble));
```

Even though the type `Foo` is coming out of left field, it works as the return type is produced solely through an "additive" pattern to what is given:

```
template <typename Target, typename Source>
shared_ptr<Target> my_normal_operator(Source src)
{
    /* ... whatever ... */
}
```

But what if the situation instead looked something like this:

```
shared_ptr<Foo> bar (my_pointer_operator<Foo*>(mumble));
```

It needs some way to pull the pointer off the type.  I dug around and found [std::remove_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer), but a naive application gives a "type/value mismatch":

```
template <typename Target, typename Source>
shared_ptr< std::remove_pointer<Target>::type > my_pointer_operator(Source src)
{
    /* ... whatever ... */
}
```

I didn't actually expect it to work...but I'm putting it here as an expression of the what-I'm-looking for intent!

*Sigh.  Every time I step into any new territory with templates and traits I feel like one of those ["I have no idea what I'm doing"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-have-no-idea-what-im-doing) meme animals.  :-/*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `typename`:

```
template <typename Target, typename Source>
shared_ptr< typename std::remove_pointer<Target>::type >
    my_pointer_operator(Source src)
{
    /* ... whatever ... */
}
```

Because the type of `std::remove_pointer<Target>::type` depends on a template argument.

Personally, I would leave `Target` as `Foo` and within the definition of `my_pointer_operator` use `typename std::add_pointer<Target>::type`, so the caller can specify the return value more directly. The function name gives away the difference in implementation.

Comment: Tx.  I actually had an inkling that it might need `typename` a moment before your answer showed up. Regardless it helps to have a second opinion that this is a valid place to use such a thing. I understand that in general one would rather be additive and as simple as possible...but I'm trying to maintain consistency among a set of routines. *I didn't understand why one would use `add_pointer` instead of just `*` until I looked it up (finessing reference types).*